# How to create a seekBar for video playing in android java and XML programming

Tags: android, video, seekbar

How to get video from device storage using intent (Video Uri) and Play the video using media player and add to seekBar for controlling the video

get video from device storage using intent (video Uri) and Play the video using media player and add to seekBar for controlling the video

Comment: You should check this url: https://exoplayer.dev

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`ExoPlayer`](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer).
Moreover, the latest version of `ExoPlayer` is published as a part of `androidx`.

They are offering UI (including `SeekBar` for controlling playback) and handle a lot of video formats which can be a hassle to support.

This is [a usage example](https://exoplayer.dev/hello-world.html).

[image]